# How to check if a string is a BigInt JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to check if a `string` is considered a `BigInt`

I have the following possible *numbers* that are returned based on a `RegEx`

```
4
5
12
76561198036527204  // This is a string but want to covert to a bigint
a-string-value     // A string can also be returned by the regex and should stay a string
true
```

The above *lines* are all returned as strings, but I want to convert them based on their type, but don't know how to validate if a `string` is a `BigInt`

A `bigint` is a `Number` that exceeds `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

I looked up if `lodash` had a function like this but it doesn't.

So the expected output from above would be

```
4 // number
5 // number
12 // number
76561198036527204  // bigint
a-string-value // string
true // bool
```

For everything I can use `lodash` except `BigInt`.

Comment: I would parse the string as a BigInt, then parse as a number and turn *that* into a BigInt, and check for equality. If they're not equal, you need the BigInt.

Comment: Afaik, this is "type conversion", not "type casting".

Comment: A string is a string, not a bigint, I don't get the question. Also why would 12 be considered a number instead of a bigint?

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I *can't* follow the OP's logic, that's why I asked for clarification. Another open question is how they want to handle a value like `76561198036527220`.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Nope, `BigInt("76561198036527204") == BigInt(+"76561198036527204")` will give you `false` whereas `BigInt("765") == BigInt(+"765")` will give you `true`. Thus, in the first case you will need a BigInt, in the second case you won't ...

Comment: @Bergi because the regex returns matches as strings, it doesnt convert those to number or booleans, or whatever.

Comment: @bergi because 12 is fits inside a 32 bit number where a bigint doesnt, so they are different. In javascript typeof bigint returns an object where number returns number. The difference is important in sense of the application.

Comment: @Bergi regarding your question about `76561198036527220`, it is bigger than the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, so in this case its a `bigint` and not a `number`.

Comment: @Red Thanks for the edit, that clarifies things. But it's really rather arbitrary, there are integers larger than `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` that can still exactly be represented as a number, and `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` has nothing to do with 32-bit (int? uint?) numbers. Btw, bigints are primitive values, `typeof` will not return "object" for them

Comment: @bergi you are right, i was logging typeof new bigint in Node 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if a string represents a `BgInt`, you could evaluate the following:

```js
function isBigInt(value) {
  try { return BigInt(parseInt(value, 10)) !== BigInt(value) }
  catch (e) { return false }
}
```

Please note, in the code that follows, that `int` is treated as a `number` in JS. This is just a refinement that was made when checking the number type.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input')
const output = document.getElementById('output')
;(input.oninput = () => {
  input.style.height = input.scrollHeight+'px'
  output.textContent = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(
    input.value.trim().split('\n').map(value => [value, inferType(value)])
  ), null, 2)
})()

function inferType(value) {
  if (isBool(value)) return 'boolean'
  if (isNumeric(value)) return inferNumericType(value)
  return 'string'
}

function inferNumericType(value) {
  if (isBigInt(value)) return 'BigInt'
  if (isInteger(value)) return 'int'
  return 'number'
}

function isBool(value) {
  switch (value?.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'true':
    case 'false':
      return true
    default:
      return false
  }
}

function isBigInt(value) {
  try { return BigInt(parseInt(value, 10)) !== BigInt(value) }
  catch (e) { return false }
}

function isNumeric(value) {
  return !isNaN(value)
}

function isInteger(value) {
  return /^\d+$/.test(value);
}
```

```css
body { display: flex; flex-direction: row }
textarea, pre { margin: 1em; padding: 0 }
```

```html
<textarea id="input">
3.14
5
12
76561198036527204
a-string-value
true
</textarea>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: This is very clever, I did not think of this, thanks.

Comment: Note that the try/catch is pretty expensive if doing this a lot - you can just check if it's a valid Number first by checking that `isNaN(Number(value))` is false :-)

Comment: @Rycochet I already did check in `inferType`.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl True - if you hit the right code path it won't hit it :-D

Answer (score 0):

Check if the parsed value matches the original value -

```
const isBigInt = (value) => String(value) === String(BigInt(value));
```

Technically that would also say that it's a valid number, so if you also checked if it was a number (lots of similar questions for that) and then discounted those first you end up with something as below:

```js
const isNumber = (value) => String(value) === String(Number(value));
const isBigInt = (value) => !isNaN(Number(value)) && String(value) === String(BigInt(value));
const isOnlyBigInt = (value) => !isNumber(value) && isBigInt(value);

console.log(
    isNumber('0'),
    isBigInt('0'),
    isOnlyBigInt('0'));

console.log(
    isNumber('1'),
    isBigInt('1'),
    isOnlyBigInt('1'));

console.log(
    isNumber('123456789123456789123456789'),
    isBigInt('123456789123456789123456789'),
    isOnlyBigInt('123456789123456789123456789'));

console.log(
    isNumber('abc'),
    isBigInt('abc'),
    isOnlyBigInt('abc'));
```

Comment: '1' is BigInt in that case

Comment: Which is where the second part comes in - and you need to check that it's not a Number (which is addressed in a lot of other questions)

Comment: I've added a code snippet

Comment: Updated that code to show the full choice :-)

Answer (score -2):

'When tested against typeof, a BigInt value (bigint primitive) will give "bigint"'

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: You might have misunderstood the problem. OP has strings and are trying to convert only suitable ones to `BigInt`s.